# how to loop through each row and delete those in which "7" has been used more than 35 times

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 400 rows and 57 variables.the answer to each variable range from 1 to 7. now I want to delete those rows in which the same number(say 7)has been used for more than 35 times, because the row is invalid in this case. 
 How can I do that(maybe with apply or for loop function)?

Comment: kindly consider adding more information about your question so that people can understand it better, e.g. your code to solve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.table(matrix(sample(x = 1:10, size = 40, replace = T), ncol = 5))
df

   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  3  6  3  7  7
2:  8  5  1  8  8
3:  5 10  4  6  1
4:  9  5 10  6  5
5: 10  7  9  3  8
6:  1  6  7  2  3
7:  6  2  7 10  4
8:  9  9 10 10  3

rowSums(df == 10) >= 2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   // The last row has two 10

# Delete the row
df[!rowSums(df == 10) >= 2]

   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  3  6  3  7  7
2:  8  5  1  8  8
3:  5 10  4  6  1
4:  9  5 10  6  5
5: 10  7  9  3  8
6:  1  6  7  2  3
7:  6  2  7 10  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` methods, we can do rowwise calculation with `pmap` to get the counts, and then `filter` to get the desired rows. If you wish, you can remove the counts column at the end. Note that I picked rows with fewer than 10 7s, since with random sampling very few had more than 35.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.1
set.seed(12345)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample.int(7, 400*57, replace = TRUE), ncol = 57))
df %>%
  mutate(num_sevens = pmap_int(., function(...) sum(c(...) == 7))) %>%
  filter(num_sevens < 10) %>%
  as_tibble
#> # A tibble: 302 x 58
#>       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     6     1     6     1     2     7     3     2     6     7     2     3
#>  2     7     4     7     6     3     5     7     6     3     5     5     5
#>  3     4     5     5     3     5     2     4     7     2     7     2     4
#>  4     2     2     1     7     2     7     3     2     3     3     6     1
#>  5     3     6     2     2     6     2     5     7     1     2     7     3
#>  6     4     2     2     2     7     3     3     7     2     6     5     4
#>  7     6     6     2     4     5     3     7     7     2     7     7     6
#>  8     7     1     2     6     6     7     3     2     6     6     7     7
#>  9     1     4     6     1     7     1     6     4     7     6     4     4
#> 10     2     6     4     2     6     4     3     5     1     3     6     7
#> # ... with 292 more rows, and 46 more variables: V13 <int>, V14 <int>,
#> #   V15 <int>, V16 <int>, V17 <int>, V18 <int>, V19 <int>, V20 <int>,
#> #   V21 <int>, V22 <int>, V23 <int>, V24 <int>, V25 <int>, V26 <int>,
#> #   V27 <int>, V28 <int>, V29 <int>, V30 <int>, V31 <int>, V32 <int>,
#> #   V33 <int>, V34 <int>, V35 <int>, V36 <int>, V37 <int>, V38 <int>,
#> #   V39 <int>, V40 <int>, V41 <int>, V42 <int>, V43 <int>, V44 <int>,
#> #   V45 <int>, V46 <int>, V47 <int>, V48 <int>, V49 <int>, V50 <int>,
#> #   V51 <int>, V52 <int>, V53 <int>, V54 <int>, V55 <int>, V56 <int>,
#> #   V57 <int>, num_sevens <int>
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

if I understood properly, you can use a loop for it:

```
## some data
Data <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 57)
Data[1, ] <- c(rep(1,36),sample(1:7,57-36, replace = TRUE))
Data[2, ] <- sample(1:7,57, replace = TRUE)
Data[3, ] <- sample(1:7,57, replace = TRUE)

## variable for storing the rows that does not match the pattern (thoose to keep)
rows <- NULL

## loop
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){
    counts <- table(Data[i, ])
    if(!any(counts > 35)) rows <- c(rows, i)
}

## filtered data
Data <- Data[rows, ]
```